# Using php to show a different header logo image if body class is home?

Tags: php, image, class, function, include

I'm working on a website where the homepage has a dark background, yet all the other pages have a white background.

I am using pho to include a header file to show the logo, navbar, telephone details etc on every page.

As the home page has a dark background, the logo has white text, yet the logo use on the other pages has dark text.

I'm looking for a way of using php, so that I include a single header file on every page. If the homepage has a class of "home" the logo image with white text is shown and on all other pages the logo image with dark text is shown.

something along these lines:

```
if (body class="home") {

<img src="images/logo-with-white-text" />

else {

<img src="images/logo-with-dark-text" />

};
```

Is this possible?

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: it's definitely possible, what's the difficulty?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming your homepage currently looks something like this:

```
<html>
    <head>...</head>
    <body class="home">
        ...
        <?php include 'header.php'; ?>
        ...
```

You could make the class a variable, and reference this variable from the included header file:

```
<?php $class = 'home'; ?>
<body class="<?php echo $class; ?>">
...
<?php include 'header.php' ?>
...
```

In header.php:

```
<?php if (isset($class) && $class == 'home'): ?>
    <img src="images/logo-with-white-text" />
<?php else: ?>
    <img src="images/logo-with-dark-text" />
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 3):

You could check whether you are on the homepage (Depending on your exact implementation) with a snippet like this:

```
if (basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']) == 'index.php') {
    // home page
}
else {
    // some other page
}
```

`$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']` contains the actually loaded file relative from the host until the query-string:

> http://example.com/my/folder.php?a=b => /my/folder.php

For more information have a look at [`basename`  in the PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/de/function.basename.php).

Answer (score 1):

`$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` contains the current page url (after the domain). You could check instead that the page has the homepage url with that.

Depending on your setup you'd have something like

```
<?php if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/') : ?>
    <img src="images/logo-with-white-text" />
<?php else: ?>
    <img src="images/logo-with-white-text" />
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need PHP for this if you use an [image replacement technique](http://css-tricks.com/css-image-replacement/) to display the image.

Basically, you use an `<h1>` or something for your logo, with text, then use negative `text-indent` to hide the text, set a height and width, and use a background image for the logo. Example:

http://jsfiddle.net/nwNbb/

```
<h1 id="logo">My Website</h1>
```

```
#logo {
 text-indent:-999px;
 background:url(/path/to/logo.png);
 height:100px;
 width:500px;   
}
```

Then, in your CSS, you can change the background image based on the body class:

```
body.home #logo {
 background:url(/path/to/alternate-logo.png);
}
```

You can actually do image replacement *on images* as well:

http://jsfiddle.net/nwNbb/3/

```
img {
     /* 500x100 replacement image */
    background:url(http://lorempixum.com/500/100);

     /* hide original image */
    width:0;
    height:0;

     /* use padding to set width/height of replacement */
    padding:50px 250px;
}
```

Comment: That's how I'd do it. Presentation belongs in the stylesheet.

Comment: It's an argument of whether the image is presentation or content. I'd say that it's both, but it's a fine line. In any case, this is how I would do it too as I always use IR for logos.

Comment: You make a valid point. I'd certainly classify an illustration as content. One could argue that a logo serves to "illustrate" a company/organization/brand, but AKAIK a logo doesn't serve a purpose outside it's presentation.

Comment: That's how I usually do things too, but on this occasion the logo is actually an image, rather than say a h1 with a negative text indent and then a background image. Bit annoying really! :P

Comment: @ade123: You can do image replacement on images themselves, see edit.

Comment: Well, there you have it. Best of both worlds. :)