# Display different header image if on home index page with php

Tags: php, url, uri

I've found a similar topic here: [Using php to show a different header logo image if body class is home?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8962230/using-php-to-show-a-different-header-logo-image-if-body-class-is-home) but it doesn't seem to suite my code.

I am trying to display a larger version of the header on the homepage of a website and smaller version on all the other pages. I have this script:

```
if(strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], "index.php") !== false) {
    echo "<img src='images/header-full.png'/>";
} else {
    echo "<img style='margin: 10px 15px 0;' src='images/header-small.png'/>";
}
```

but that only shows it if they click on the 'home' nav link and 'index.php' is located in the URL. How can I tell if the user is on the homepage even without the 'index.php' in the URL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You certainly could do something like this:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == "/" || $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == "/index.php") {
...
```

Comment: Thank you! Worked perfectly. I dunno why I couldn't figure that out. I'll accept the answer as soon as it will let me.